# Qual a forma correta de utilizar o "à"? ("a" com crase)

Tags: gramática, crase

Gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor forma de utilizar o "a" com crase, pois nunca tenho a certeza de que estou correto, quando venho a utiliza-lo.

### Exemplo

> "A solução para o problema veio à tona"

Comment: Não devia ser "a a" com crase?

Comment: mas o que é crase?

Comment: @JorgeB. cria uma pergunta. :)

Comment: @JorgeB. A fusão de duas vogais iguais, alterando-se a pronúncia. è usado para tornar a linguagem mais dinâmica.

Answer (score 12):

Há uma distinção importante entre crase e acento grave. Crase é um fenômeno linguístico (fonológico, acima de tudo) que pode ocorrer no seguinte contexto: duas palavras são pronunciadas em sequência, tais que o último som da primeira palavra é igual ao primeiro som da segunda palavra e esse som é uma vogal. Ocorre crase quando os falantes reduzem a pronúncia a apenas uma sílaba. Por exemplo:

> Casa amarela.

Alguns falantes podem pronunciar algo como "casamarela", enquanto outros irão pronunciar o "a" duas vezes, demarcando a separação por um pequeno espaço de tempo ou, menos comumente, usando a [oclusiva glotal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oclusiva_glotal) [ʔ]. No caso em que o "a" é pronunciado apenas uma vez, diz-se que houve crase.

Alguns tipos de crase, no entanto, são marcados explicitamente na ortografia, usando-se o acento grave (`):

1. No encontro entre a preposição "a" com o artigo definido feminino singular "a": "Fui a a casa", que acaba sendo grafado como "Fui à casa".
2. No encontro entre a preposição "a" com o pronome "aquele" (e suas variações "aquela", "aqueles", "aquilo"): "fui a aquele lugar", que normalmente se escreve "fui àquele lugar".

Comment: ficou meio confuso de entender, mas acho que entendi(porém não tenho certeza)

Comment: @PauloRoberto o problema está na tua pergunta. As duas coisas de que falas não estão relacionadas. Crase é uma coisa e acentuação grave em contracções de preposições é outra coisa diferente. A resposta explica isso bastante bem, na minha opinião.

Comment: @Joum acho que entendi o problema, pra mim crase é o acento ao contrário utilizado no a: "à" só que na verdade crase é o "a a" kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk que burro

Comment: As fontes que consultei, Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) e [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crase), não incluem em crase coisas como a pronúncia  de *casa amarela* como se fosse *casamarela* ; incluem apenas as fusões permanentes de vogais idênticas como *dolor > door > dor* ou *a a > à*;

Comment: Vale notar que em pt-BR "crase" também é um sinônimo de "acento grave" nesse contexto, cf. [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/crase): "2. [Brasil]  Acento grave colocado para assinalar uma crase."

Answer (score 4):

Usa-se crase, fenômeno indicado pelo pelo acento grave (`), quando há a fusão entre duas vogais iguais, normalmente entre o *artigo* `a` e a *preposição* `a`.

Exemplos:

> Fui à cidade.

**Ocorre crase.**

> Conheço a cidade.

Conheço - verbo transitivo direto – não exige preposição

a - artigo

cidade - substantivo feminino

**Não há crase.**

Comment: Se não estou em erro, é também correto dizer _Fui a a cidade._, apesar de incomum, o que torna claro que uma crase deveria ocorrer.

Answer (score 1):

A crase, ou acento grave (`)  acontece para marcar a fusão entre duas letras "a" que ocorreriam juntas, geralmente a preposição "a" e o artigo definido feminino "a", mas também pode acontecer no pronome "aquela".

A regra mais simples que você se valer para identificar é a seguinte: se você consegue trocar o substantivo ao qual o artigo definido feminino se refere por um substantivo masculino e aparecer a construção "ao", significa que a construção original necessita de uma crase em "à".

Por exemplo, se tem dúvida se há ou não a crase em

> Farei uma viagem a França.

Tente trocar o objeto por um substantivo masculino e tente montar a frase.

> Farei uma viagem ao Marrocos.

A frase pede o aparecimento da construção "ao" quando se utiliza o objeto masculino pois a locução verbal "Farei uma viagem" é transitiva indireta, ou seja, demanda uma preposição "a".  Quem faz uma viagem, faz uma viagem *a* algum lugar.  Portanto a frase correta acima seria *"Farei uma viagem à França"*.

Vê-se que conhecer bem o uso da crase depende de se conhecer bem as [regências](https://www.wikiwand.com/pt/Reg%C3%AAncia_(lingu%C3%ADstica)) verbal e nominal para se ter certeza de que se demanda a preposição "a" em cada caso.

No exemplo que você cita, **"à tona"** é uma expressão, portanto já é consagrada pelo uso exatamente com essa grafia.  De acordo com https://www.coladaweb.com/portugues/uso-da-crase-quando-ha-ou-nao-crase, sempre utiliza-se crase nesses casos:

> 13) Em locuções adverbiais, conjuntivas ou prepositivas formadas por
>   palavras femininas:
>
> Adverbiais: às pressas, à tarde, à noite, à toa, às escondidas, à
>   força, às cegas. Conjuntivas: à proporção que, à medida que. (Exceção:
>   a prestação.) Prepositivas: à falta de, à espera de, à vista de, à
>   beira de.

Answer (score 1):

Repare que se eliminar a parte final da frase, fica com:

> A solução para o problema veio (a algum lado).

Isto é, o verbo exige ser seguido de uma proposição, que estabeleça a ligação com o grupo nominal - neste caso, "a toa".

Repare que podia igualmente escrever: "A solução para o problema veio de cima" ou "A solução para o problema veio do livro". No segundo caso, ocorre a fusão entre "de" e o artigo "o", no entanto, no primeiro, não é necessário fazê-lo, porque "cima" não é antecedido por um determinante.

Assim, no caso de usar a proposição "a" e um nome que seja antecedido de um artigo ("o", "a", "os", "as"), deve proceder à fusão ("ao", "à", "aos", "às", respectivamente).

Em caso de dúvida, tente separar o nome/grupo nominal, usá-lo noutra frase, e perceber se ele tem de ser antecedido do artigo ("a") ou não, para perceber se ocorre essa fusão ou se usa só a proposição "a".