# O que é a crase?

Tags: ortografia, crase

Vendo esta pergunta [Qual a forma correta de utilizar o "à"? ("a" com crase)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/142/qual-a-forma-correta-de-utilizar-o-%C3%A0-a-com-crase?noredirect=1#comment294_142) fiquei com a dúvida sobre o que é a crase.

Comment: Você tem uma pergunta mais específico? Já viu a pagina na Wikipedia? https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crase

Comment: Mais especifica como assim? Só quero saber o que é um crase.

Comment: Então, tem uma explicação simples na Wikipedia...

Comment: @Earthliŋ mas não tem aqui. A maioria das perguntas que vi até agora tem como resposta explicações de outros sites que eu já tinha visto. Isso não impede de ter uma boa base de informação aqui.

Comment: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-we-try-to-populate-this-site-with-questions e http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/sobre-quest%C3%B5es-superficiais

Comment: @Earthliŋ mas é que saber o que é um "crase" não é nada básico. Tenho a certeza que muita gente não sabe.

Comment: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/24/153

Comment: Não é básico, mas a forma da sua questão é muito simples. Geralmente (no Stack Exchange) uma questão é bom se ela mostra "research effort" (veja o texto do "upvote button").

Comment: @Earthliŋ para já ela está com pontuação positiva, o que quer dizer que a comunidade gostou da pergunta. Esse aspeto já foi discutido várias vezes no SOpt e não se chegou a nenhuma conclusão. A discussão do meta daqui também está na mesma. Eu até agora não vi nenhuma pergunta a mostrar esforço de pesquisa, se mostrasse não estava aqui nenhuma. Todas as resposta que vi até agora estão em primeiro nas pesquisas do google.

Comment: Relacionada: [Uso do acento diferencial - ocorrência de crase](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/820/uso-do-acento-diferencial-ocorr%C3%AAncia-de-crase)

Comment: Eu imagino que as respostas com o tempo dirão se essa pergunta foi válida ou não, se vai valer a pena manter ou não, creio que possa ter muito a acrescentar e nos surpreender, é diferente de algo estático e sem direito a um debate como o Wikipidia, são propósitos distintos, o fato de já haver uma página lá não impede de uma pergunta aqui acrescentar e muito esse tópico.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Crase é um fenómeno fonológico que torna a fala mais fluida e dinâmica; caracteriza-se pela fusão de duas vogais iguais, alterando a pronúncia.

Por exemplo *bola azul* pode ser pronunciada como *bolazul* removendo a pequena pausa que havia no meio.

Na escrita este fenómeno é um método de formação de palavras. Por exemplo, *Fui a a escola* (onde o primeiro *a* é uma preposição e o segundo um determinante) evoluiu para *Fui à escola*.

Comment: As fontes que consultei, Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) e [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crase), não incluem em crase coisas como a pronúncia  de *bola azul* como se fosse *bolazul* ; incluem apenas as fusões permanentes de vogais idênticas como *dolor > door > dor* ou *a a > à*;

Answer (score -1):

Crase é fusão da preposição *a* com o artigo definido *a*.

Essa fusão de vogais idênticas é conhecida por crase.

Comment: Mas então e no caso de "a" + "o" = "ao"? É crase, ou não? Gostava que a tua resposta respondesse a isso.