# Uso do acento diferencial - ocorrência de crase

Tags: crase

No exemplo a seguir:

> O Brasil resiste as mudanças políticas.

Ocorre crase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta correta seria "ocorre crase"?

Sim, e porque afirmo que ela ocorre?   Não porque o verbo seja transitivo direto ou indireto, ou intransitivo.  **Há crase porque existe em "as mudanças políticas" o artigo definido "as" somado a preposição "a".** - O acento grave não é a crase, é apenas o "indicador de sua ocorrência.

Chamamos de "crase" a somação da preposição "a" ao artigo definido "a/as".  Portanto neste caso só ocorre crase antes de palavras do gênero feminino. Pode também ocorrer crase quando a preposição "a"  precede pronomes demonstrativos que se iniciam pela letra "a", independente do gênero (aquele, aquela, aquilo)

**Como saber se ocorre crase?**  Se a palavra é "as", é claro que o artigo está presente pois a preposição não vai ao plural sozinha.  Neste caso temos que identificar se há preposição também.  Se a palavra é "a" tentamos evidenciar o artigo.  Como fazemos isso?  Substituindo o objeto feminino por um masculino.  Caso "a" seja transformado em "ao", é porque existe também o artigo definido.  Caso "as" seja transformado em "aos", é porque existe também preposição.

Ex:

- O banheiro está cheirando **a** acetona.
- O banheiro está cheirando **a** desinfetante. (não existe artigo, apenas preposição)
- O João foi **à** praia.
- O joão foi **ao** cinema. (existe o artigo e a preposição, portanto há crase)
- O Brasil resiste **às** pressões internacionais. Neste caso é obvio que temos o artigo pois a preposição não vai ao plural. Portanto vamos procurar a preposição substituindo o objeto feminino por um masculino: o Brasil resiste **aos** apelos internacionais.  (há crase, pois existe preposição)

Comment: Não entendi nada. Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: @JorgeB. Tentei explicar melhor.

Comment: Entendi agora :) +1

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é um crase?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/280/o-que-%C3%A9-um-crase)

Answer (score 3):

Sim. "Resistir", neste caso, [é verbo transitivo indireto](http://www.lpeu.com.br/q/367sf).

"Mudança" possui gênero feminino, portanto é necessário o uso da crase:

> O Brasil resiste às mudanças políticas.