# Porque existe o acento grave?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

Porque temos, em Português, um acento grave só para três ou quatro palavras? (à, àquilo, àquele...)

Qual a justificação para usarmos nelas um acento grave e não um agudo, como em "todos os outros casos"?

---

[Na Wikipédia diz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o_gr%C3%A1fica#Acento_grave) que o acento grave é usado para marcar a crase...
Mas [no artigo sobre crase](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crase) o primeiro exemplo é `noo -> nó`, com acento agudo.

Comment: Em abono da justiça, o artigo na WP sobre crase está *muito* fraquinho. Confunde a crase com o uso ou não do artigo, que é o que acaba por causar a crase.

Comment: Sobre o attigo da WP, note que "crase" é um fenômeno fonético. A crase é o processo pelo qual uma palavra que continha duas vogais juntas passou a ter só uma. Foi o que aconteceu como "nó" e "ser". Ocorre que "nó" recebe o acento agudo _não_ devido à crase, mas por ser um monossílabo tônico terminado em "o". Note como "ser" também é monossílabo tônico resultante de crase, mas como termina em "r" não leva acento.

Comment: @brandizzi mas e "à", não é também um monossílabo tónico? Porque não leva igualmente acento agudo, como "nó"? Essa é a principal pergunta que tenho.

Comment: "à" não é tônico, acredito: dificilmente o "à" seria a palavra mais forte em uma oração. Uma regra bobinha que adoto para saber se o monossílabo é tônico é usá-lo em uma rima. Por exemplo, se eu fizesse um poeminha "decidi que vou à / montanha que está lá", a rima soa estranha, porque o "à" é bem fraquinho. Mas mesmo que fosse tônico, acredito que usaria o acento grave, para acabar com a ambiguidade com outras palavas idênticas.

Answer (score 7):

A principal diferença é o facto de o acento agudo (e, hoje, o circunflexo) marcar a vogal tónica, contrariamente ao acento grave.

As palavras *àquilo* e *àqueloutro*, por exemplo, são paroxítonas.

Da mesma forma, na grafia portuguesa anterior à reforma ortográfica de 1973, escrevia-se *rápido* (proparoxítona), mas *ràpidamente* (paroxítona).

Comment: Aaaah! Uau, faz imenso sentido. Fica por responder: porque é que não se escreve "à" com acento agudo, ou "nós" com grave? Se ambas são crases e ambas têm o acento na sílaba tónica.

Comment: @ANeves Já se escreveu ***á***. Imagino que agora se escreva ***à*** por coerência com *àquele*, etc. Não poderíamos escrever _*áquele_, porque na grafia pós 1911 em Portugal e pós 1943 no Brasil, o acento agudo indica sempre a vogal tónica.

Answer (score 3):

A partir de uma reforma ortográfica ocorrida na segunda metade do século passado, o acento grave passou a ser usado apenas para registrar a ocorrência de crase.  Note bem que **o acento grave não é sinônimo de crase**, mas sim um indicativo de sua ocorrência.

> - **crase é a contração ou fusão de sons vogais num só.**
>
> exemplos: fusão do artigo definido feminino "a" ou "as" com a preposição "a" = "à" ou "às"
>
> fusão do artigo definido "a" ou "as" com os pronomes demonstrativos "aquele", "aquela" ou "aquilo" = "àquele", "àquela", ou "àquilo".

Para saber mais sobre o quando e onde usar o acento grave, temos já algumas perguntas sobre a crase [**aqui**](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/820/uso-do-acento-diferencial-ocorr%C3%AAncia-de-crase) e também [**aqui**](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/142/qual-a-forma-correta-de-utilizar-o-%C3%A0-a-com-crase).

Comment: (1) Eu sei quando usar o acento grave, Centaurus, em todas as contrações do artigo "a" com uma palavra começada por "a-": à, àquele, etc. Em Portugal o "a" e o "à" soam diferente, então essa não é uma dificuldade que tenhamos. (2) E tudo bem que o acento grave não é sinónimo de crase, *mas então porque há um acento agudo na palavra nós*? Que justificação se encontra, que não se aplicasse para escrever também "á" (sic)?

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/acento-grave/313), o acento grave é usado para

> marcar a contracção por crase.

([Fonte](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/acento-grave/313)).

Como por exemplo

> a) prep. a + art. a/as - à, às;
>
> b) prep. a + aquele/a/es/as - àquele, a/àqueles/as;
>
> c) prep. a + aquilo - àquilo;
>
> d) prep. a + aqueloutro/a/s/as - àquleoutro/a/os/as;
>
> e) comò, comà, comòs, comàs, em que há contracção de coma (pop. e
> arcaico = como) + o, artigo;
>
> f) prò, prà, pròs, pràs, contracção de pra (redução de para) com o o,
> a, os, as, quer sejam artigos, quer pronomes.
>
> g) Quando é preciso distinguir duas formas paralelas, em que a mesma sílaba é fechada ou aberta, como se dá no vocábulo regional àgora.
>
> h) Quando queremos transcrever a pronúncia popular como por exemplo em prèguntar.

Algumas considerações extra:

• A alínea f) só é usado quando pretendemos representar a pronúncia popular ou corrente.

• Não se faz a contracção de a + o pronome demonstrativo aquele, quando o devemos grafar com inicial maiúscula por se referir a uma entidade de muito respeito, como por exemplo Deus, Nossa Senhora, etc, Ex.: - Todos os dias oro a Aquele a quem devo a vida.